# Get First and Last child keys in Firebase from Parent node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a small app that manages dates in Android Studio.
For this I created the following db in Firebase:

[image]

All dates are in format `YYYYMMDD`.
I wish to retrieve the first and last child's keys of `config` node (i.e.  `20190101` and  let's say `20211231`).

I used two callback functions from a `Callback` abstract class for each of the dates.

My code :

```
public class Validator{
     public static void getMinMaxDatesFromDB(final Callback callback)
        {
            FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("config");
            // Get First Date from Firebase
            ref.limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        callback.minDate(snapshot.getKey());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
            // Get Last Date from Firebase
            ref.limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        callback.maxDate(snapshot.getKey());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

And the caller:

```
// Date format - YYYYMMDD (String)
Validator.getMinMaxDatesFromDB(new Callback() {
    @Override
    void minDate(String minDate) {
        super.minDate(minDate);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(minDate.substring(0,3));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(minDate.substring(4,5));
        int day = Integer.parseInt(minDate.substring(6,7));
        //some more logic
    }

    @Override
    void maxDate(String maxDate) {
        super.maxDate(maxDate);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(maxDate.substring(0,3));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(maxDate.substring(4,5));
        int day = Integer.parseInt(maxDate.substring(6,7));
        // some more logic 
    }
});
```

But I'm getting `"config"` in `minDate` instead of `"20190101"`.

I'd appreciate help.

P.S. In addition, I'd also like to know if there is a better way of retrieving the first and last child of a specific node without the use of loops, or is callbacks my only option?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Oh, yes I have. This question is no longer relevant.